# Restricting match output for multiple sequence alignment using mafft?

Tags: sequence-alignment

So I aligned roughly 5k sequences and I got my output using mafft. However, I want to restrict the output to only present conserved segments of a specific length (let's say 25bp). Does mafft have parameters to set this that I seem to be missing?

Answer (score 2):

### Q - Is there some parameter for this?

No, there is no parameter for this. Getting the conserved regions is something that you will have to perform post-alignment.

### How to get the conserved regions?

You will need to define what exactly you mean by conservation and calculate a conservation score for each position of the alignment.

For instance you can look at each column of the alignment and calculate the percent of queries that had the same base/AA at that position. If using AAs you can define conservation more loosely depending on what properties are important to you, or using a scoring matrix.

Once you have a co-occurrence matrix you can define the regions of interest based on a conservation threshold that you define.

### Is there software to find conserved columns?

There is a program [MstatX](https://github.com/gcollet/MstatX) which outputs conservation scores of individual columns.

### How MstatX works

The example of MstatX provides this example alignment. Each column is progressively less conserved than the last. The last column is conserved, but has some gaps -- this lowers the conservation score.

```
   col          1
 seq1  1234567890
 seq2  DDDDDDIPDL
 seq3  DDDDDDIPVL
 seq4  DDDDDDIPYL
 seq5  DDDDDDIPA-
 seq6  DDDDDDLWT-
 seq7  DDEDEELWK-
 seq8  DDEDEELWP-
 seq9  DDEDEFVSR-
 seq10 DEEFFFVSH-
```

The conservation scores for each column were:

```
1       2.71272e-08
2       0.243433
3       0.312789
4       0.243433
5       0.483364
6       0.480391
7       0.498757
8       0.498757
9       0.973514
10      0.267319
```

### How to get conserved regions

The python program below will output all windows of conserved regions when using a fasta alignment and the default output from `MstatX`.

- Positional args

  - **1.** `MstatX_alignment_example.mali`, is the fasta alignment file.
  - **2.** `output.txt` is the default output of `mstatx` when called with `mstatx -i MstatX_alignment_example.mali`.
  - **3.** 0.4 is the minimum conservation score
  - **4.** 3 is the minimum number of bases that must have that conservation score.

Calling this program with the following command on the above example:

`python print_conserved_regions.py MstatX_alignment_example.mali output.txt 0.4 3` prints:

```
{1,4}
```

Meaning that there was only one window at least 3 bases long in which all positions had a conservation score below 0.4. This window was positions 1 through 4 in the alignment.

```py
#call this file cons_windows.py
import sys
from Bio import AlignIO

align_filename = sys.argv[1]
cons_filename = sys.argv[2]
cutoff = float(sys.argv[3])
minchar = int(sys.argv[4])

def parse_conservation(filename):
    cons = {}
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip():
                temp = line.split()
                cons[int(temp[0])] = float(temp[1])
    return cons

align = AlignIO.read(align_filename, "fasta")
cons = parse_conservation(sys.argv[2])

i = 1
while i < max(cons):
    if cons[i] <= cutoff:
        j = i
        done = False
        while j < max(cons) and not done:
            if (cons[j] > cutoff) and (j-i >= minchar):
                print("{{{},{}}}".format(i,j-1))
                done = True
                i = j
            j+=1
    i+=1
```